# How to design form tags button in html

Tags: html, forms

I have a button that is this `<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>` the problem is, I want the form tags to use this id so that is designed the way I want. And also this code, I have a few questions.

```
<form action="demo_form.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

what is the `action="demo_form.php"`,`input type="submit"` do? And does the `input type` has any other "What do you call this stuff" besides `submit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action="demo_form.php"` sets the action, in this case, "navigate to file demo_form.php and send it the data".

`<input type="submit" (...) >` creates and element which submits the form e.g. executes the "action".

The `method` sets the way the data is submitted to the target of the action ("form_demo.php"), in this case `get`, which allows you to refer to the submitted data as `$GET["name"]` in PHP.

Possible input types are listed [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

You either give your `<input type="submit" (...) >` the `id="btnSubmit"` property or use javascript to submit the form after an event has been triggered.
MOr info on that is available [here](http://www.formget.com/javascript-submit-form/) (i  short: `document.<get_the_form_element>.submit();`).

Comment: I don't have any basic knowledge in javascript right now, does what you say in the former of the 4th paragraph will do just fine withouth javascript?

Comment: @WTFZane If you add the `id="btnSubmit"` to your `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` tag it should have the same effect as creating a `<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>` and using javascript to trigger the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). It describes all the basic concepts about how using forms. And you can also find a lot of information by Googling it.

The action attribute

> The action attribute defines the action to be performed when the form is submitted.
>   The common way to submit a form to a server, is by using a submit button.

The input attribute

> `<input type="submit">` defines a button for submitting a form to a form-handler.
>   The form-handler is typically a server page with a script for processing input data.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, these are my answers.

**action**

The action attribute describes the page to which the contents of the form are sent to. So if you have a sign up form with an input for an email, the text that is typed will be sent to the action path. It will be sent using the method described in the **method** attribute. So you can find your values in either the $_POST variable, or the $_GET variable, get is easy for being able to share the url and post is great for private information.

**input**

The input element is the actual way to input information (who guessed it). You've got an input of the type text for just text input, you've got checkbox for a true or false input and way way more see: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
```

Or if you want to use a button

```
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Then from jquery or js you can submit the form.

And for this question, 
what is the action="demo_form.php",input type="submit" do?
You should probably google it out. This is so basic.

Anyway, just a concise explanation:

`action` is the attribute where you will specify the code that will handle the form data submitted and `input type="submit"` will display a button in the page, clicking on it will submit the form.

There are a lot of types in input, the most common ones are

```
text
password
submit
```